# Adding minimum margin between roads in QGIS

Tags: qgis, road, streets, offset

I'm wondering if there's a way to add a minimum space between roads that are too close together in a map. Accuracy is not my goal, I just want to make it visually as clear and clean as possible. Could I somehow add a minimum number of meters as a margin between roads?

Comment: You should add more context and probably a screenshot: are roads on the same layer? You want to shift just the segments of the road that is close to another road? etc.

Comment: Have a look here to get some ideas: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/403973/88814