# Making space between line features on different scales using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, symbology, line, scale

I have a feature class layer where linear features will often be digitised close to each other. These lines are all features in the same layer.

Example when zoomed in:

[image]

Problem when zooming out to export wider map:

[image]

When I zoom out, the 3 line symbols overlap each other.I want the lines to retain a decent thickness but not battle each other for space. I want them to automatically detect they are close to each other and line up side by side, or spaced out a bit for clarity. Like:

[image: ![Result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B4KC.png[![][1]][1])]

I've seen solutions to solve this problem on QGIS, but my project is on ArcGIS Pro.

Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried looking at "resolve road conflicts"? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/cartography/resolve-road-conflicts.htm

It looks like if you are going for this effect in a static map, this would work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your intention with your map. The fact you are zooming in/out would suggest to me that you intend to use this map only in the GIS software. Paper maps can't zoom in/out, well not at least the last time I looked.

If you are wanting your symbology to move as you change scale, then typically one would create duplicate layers and have them turn on/off as you change map scale. These are properties of the layer.

[image: Layer properties]

But you are also asking to move them so you can interpret the data better. I would explore in ArcGIS Pro the ability to offset your symbology from the underlining geometry, it Is a property of the symbol.

[image: Symbology properties]

With a combination of off-setting and layer visibility thresholds you should achieve something close to what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Hornbydd, I edited my post to explain what I'm expecting. The layer visibility and offset is an option, but it's not automatic and seems like a lot of work. I was wondering if there is any automation to do here, like in QGIS (see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403956/making-space-between-tight-line-features-on-different-scales-in-qgis) )